# C malloc failure

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I've stumbled upon a problem of memory allocation. I am writing a simple application that is supposed to read files and get information from them. It is supposed to be very simple (single threaded) so I was wondering what should I do if `malloc()` or `calloc()` fails?

Should the function `exit()` the program with some error message or return `NULL`(or other appropriate return value) and try to allocate memory again?

Comment: If the malloc fails the best thing is just abort. you may have not enough resources to even print the error message.

Comment: I'd suggest to exit with code 12 (`12 ENOMEM Out of memory`)

Comment: If memory allocation fails then there is no reason to expect that trying again will succeed unless you release some allocated memory in between.

Comment: @IłyaBursov, `errno` codes are for functions to provide information to their callers in the event of failure.  It is not conventional to use them as program exit statuses, and because it is not conventional, it also is not very useful -- people will not ordinarily interpret exit statuses as `errno` codes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger by exit I meant abort application, not return to caller, and people do interpret exit code as errno, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326766/what-are-the-standard-error-codes-in-linux

Comment: @IłyaBursov, I know what you meant by "exit", and my comment responds to that.  And I'm sorry, but no, people do not ordinarily interpret program exit statuses as `errno` codes, and the link you provided does not suggest otherwise.  That's not to say that nobody ever does it, but again, it is not conventional.  It is common to use `perror()` or `strerror()` to output diagnostic messages derived from `errno` codes, but that is a different thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I saw many applications follow this "standard", so for me it is "conventional" enough, especially when [quite popular applications](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operating-system-error-codes/) follow that scheme, despite that there is no strict standard, and apps are free to use any non-zero code to indicate failure, I usually expect windows app to return 5 to indicate no access or linux one to return 2 if file is not found and quite often my expectations are correct, just because it is much easier to write program which returns errno or GetLastError in case of failure

Comment: One technique I've used in the past re: `malloc()` failures is, at program startup, allocate a pretty good-sized chunk of memory just to have lying around, and if we run out of memory, *one time* release that emergency buffer back to the arena.  Then we'd have small bits of memory available in order to perform an orderly cleanup (flush data to files, close databases, log an error, message the user, etc.). Most programs don't need this kind of support.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Now I will just exit whenever ```malloc()``` or ```calloc()``` can't allocate memory.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I would never have thought of that. That's actually very very clever and insightful. To have emergency memory in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Citation needed, @IłyaBursov.  You have not yet presented evidence that any tool uses `perror` codes as exit statuses.  Do, however, read the comments on the question at the first link you posted, which support my claim.  You seem to be focusing on tools and support (in particular, the `perror` command-line tool) that *interpret* `errno` codes, but this has nothing to do with whether programs use such codes as their exit statuses.  The MariaDB link, for example, is in the documentation for how to use the Maria API, not its command-line tools.

Comment: We probably need more details here. If your program is trying to allocate memory for the *entire* file and that fails, then you can possibly allocate a smaller chunk and read/process the file in segments.

Comment: @AdrianMole I added the 


"[I am writing a simple application that is supposed to read files and get information from them.]"


just for some context. The intention of the question is more about ```malloc()``` and ```calloc()``` failure and what to do in case one or the other fails.

Comment: What you should do depends on the context. If your program logic can handle attempting to allocate less memory, then that's an option to try. If your program simply can't function without the requested/failed amount of memory, then you'll have to exit, in one way or another.

Comment: @AdrianMole It does not depend on the context. Read the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger here is example from some chromium sample https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/autotest/+/master/client/tests/rtc/src/rtctest.c#58

Comment: And how hard did you have to search to find that, @IłyaBursov?  And is that behavior documented, or merely an implementation detail?  In such an obscure program, too. This is my point. None of the standard system utilities behave that way, or at least they are not documented to do.  Few other utilities do.  It is therefore of little use in general because people do not expect to be able to rely on it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger [first page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22exit%28errno%29%22) I'm not saying that all applications follow this structure, but some of them definitely are and it is very helpful sometimes, as soon as you can use any code to indicate failure - why should you invent something, when it is already there

Comment: Sometimes Google, amazes me, @IłyaBursov.  Nevertheless, try reading some of the other results that search turns up, including the many that talk about how exiting with `errno` as the status code is neither standard nor even common.  Don't overlook [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590154/289373) that describes a specific problem (a minor one, to be sure) that would be associated with the practice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I saw this answer and agree with it, but still suggest to use `exit(12);` on linux or `0x8` for windows to indicate memory allocation failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If malloc fails you basically have 3 options:

1. free some memory and try again.
2. don't allocate and do something else instead.
3. exit the program.

assuming you needed the memory to store some data then 2 wouldn't be an option, and in that case you either do 1 or 3.

No one can predict all possible programs, but one reason I could see trying to allocate but not using memory was in a program where you were just testing to see how much you could allocate on a system under a given load.

Anyway I think 1 or 3 are probably most cases.